# Duplicating lines in a file with Perl

Tags: perl

I thought this would be insanely easy but I'm stumped.  I want to take each line in a file and duplicate it eight times.  Here is the code that I'm using:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use diagnostics;


my $inputFile = "Providers list.csv";
my $outputFile = "Providers list2.csv";
open my $FHI, '<', $inputFile || die "cannot open input file";
open my $FHO, '>', $outputFile || die "cannot open output file";

while (<$FHI>) {
    for ( my $i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
    print $FHO "$_\r";
}
}

close $inputFile;
close $outputFile;
```

What is happening is instead of each line getting duplicated eight times it's repeating the entire file contents eight times.  In other words, instead of this:

```
Line1
Line1
Line1
Line1
Line1
Line1
Line1
Line1
```

I'm getting this:

```
Line1
Line2
Line3
Line1
Line2
Line3
```

Etc., eight times.  I don't understand why it's not processing each line individually.

TIA!

Comment: Why are you printing carriage returns (`"\r"`) in your loop?

Comment: Because the file is going to be used on system running classic Mac OS which uses carriage returns as line ends.

Comment: You should be closing `$FHI` and `$FHO`, not the file names.  That isn't the source of your bug, though.  Otherwise, I think @Andy is giving you the answer you need - you are actually only reading 'one line' in, and that is the whole file, leading to the behaviour you are seeing.

Comment: A minor comment: `open $fd, "<", $file || die "..."`; will not catch errors, and will die with a perfectly legal file named `0`. Use   the `or` operator instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably reading a Mac file on a non-Mac platform.

In this case, another option is to convert the line endings outside of your script: it has the advantage that the script itself can be executed unaltered on any platform/source file combination, but of course it's slower (compared to Andy's suggestion).

It consists of three steps: first the newlines conversion (supposing you're on *nix):

```
perl -pe 's/\r/\n/g' macfile.csv > unixfile.csv
```

then your script (without appending `\r` when printing, as already said by Andy), or simply from the command line:

```
perl -l0ne 'print "$_\n" x 8' unixfile.csv > unixfile8.csv
```

which, if you're sure that your original file terminates with a newline, can be further reduced to:

```
perl -ne 'print $_ x 8' unixfile.csv > unixfile8.csv
```

and finally:

```
perl -pe 's/\n/\r/g' unixfile8.csv > macfile8.csv
```

About your script: just remember that `use diagnostics` automatically activates `warnings` as well, and that the preferred style for Perl variable names is `$all_lowercase_with_underscore`.

Also have a look at [Perl newlines across different platforms](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html#Newlines)

Answer (score 6):

If the source file also has Mac line endings, try setting the input record separator with `$/ = "\r"` at the start of the script. If that is the issue, then you don't need to also print the `\r` with the output, as long as you haven't `chomp`ed the data.

Answer (score 1):

The `x` operator can be used to print something multiple times, so

```
print $_ x 8;
```

Comment: Thanks, I had forgotten that.